# Use a UI phone as the default interface for kivy in python

Tags: python, user-interface, flutter, kivy

I was watching some videos of Flutter, and it was impressive that Flutter has a Phone and you can see the phone with the app like this:

[image]

Also in kivy we make apps but when we run it we have the default interface like this one:

[image]

The thing is that I would like to change the image of the default display interface, or the figure of the ui to an iphone, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter doesn't have a phone as you say. That is an iPhone simulator or an Android emulator. You can get an emulator by installing android studio (Android SDK to be precise ) and a simulator by installing Xcode. After the installation, you can then compile your kivy app into a package and run it on the android emulator or simulator.

Follow this [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html) to see how to compile for Android.

Comment: can I program in android studio with python kivy?

Comment: Android Studio supports all the same programming languages of IntelliJ (and CLion) e.g. Java, C++, and more with extensions, such as Go; and Android Studio 3.0 or later supports Kotlin and "all Java 7 language features and a subset of Java 8 language features that vary by platform version.". With this said, I will not recommend writing python in android studio. Microsoft visual studio is already well suited for that. Just install Android SDK and take advantage of the emulator as you wanted. Note: that you can't have a simulator without Mac OS. You can also run you kivy on real android device.

Comment: yes it works, but I would like better installing the emulator in pycharm jaja but it works, if you an idea of an emulator in pycharm tell me thanks

Comment: Android emulator is in the Android SDK which makes it independent from Android studio and consequently any other IDE. So you can as well install you Pycharm modify your source code and compiler as you usually do.